# Does Jasmine support javascript with => (arrow)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, arrow-functions

Jasmine doesn't seem to support `=>` (if my own findings are correct).

This is a snippet from my `logic.js` file

```
var myObj = new function(){
    this.getSomething = function(input){
        _myLocalArray.forEach(item =>{
            //left blank
        });
    };
};
```

My test is

```
/// <reference path="../../Ui/Content/Javascript/logic.js"/>
/// <reference path="jasmine.js" />

describe("My Tests", function () {

it("Description etc", function () {
    var result = myObj.getSomething("some input"); // FAILS HERE
    expect(result.length).toBe(0);
});
...
```

It fails with

> JavaScript critical error at line 61, column 37 in file:///d:/github/Ui/Content/Javascript/logic.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Line 61 is shown in th3e code snippet above with //FAILS HERE

and then an exception in Jasmine is thrown which is

> myObj is undefined

If I comment out the code in logic (where I use `=>`) then the code executes without these errors

What am I doing wrong? Is `=>` not supported? I find nothing in the docs to confirm this.

*EDIT*

I am not use nodeJs. I'm using vanilla javascript, visual studio 2017, Jasmine and Chutzpah.

Comment: What is in *line 61, column 37*? Also, are you using *NodeJS*? Which version? Did you check the links in my answer?

Comment: Upated my question. I'm not use node. Line 61 is the same line I show in the code snippet with //FAILS HERE @CastroRoy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite important:

> I'm using vanilla javascript, visual studio 2017, Jasmine and Chutzpah.

first, there is no *vanilla javascript*! Or at least, node does not mean you dont use *vanilla javascript*. The **only** meaning of *vanilla javascript*  is that you don't use any framework/library. However you *always* need something to execute your javascript. Either a browser or something else like `node`. There are other options however, for example *Nashorn*, *GraalVM* or *Duktape*.

Jasmine is a library written is Javascript. So Jasmine has nothing to do with the supported Javascript features. However *Chutzpah* has. So how does *Chutzpah* execute your javascript? Well, the [readme](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah) answers this question:

> Chutzpah supports the QUnit, Jasmine and Mocha testing frameworks. Chutzpah uses the PhantomJS headless browser to run your tests.

and here is your answer: [Phantomjs does not support arrow functions!](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-arrow_functions)

Actually [phantomjs is dead](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344) and should be replaced by things like Chrome Headless. Also the activity on `Chutzpah` looks not very promising. So I can just recommend you to step away from `Chutzpah` for now, and use somthing that uses Chrome Headless under the hood.